# A message if beforesave returns false - yii2

Tags: yii2

In my invitation model, I have a before save function, which checks and returns false, if there are already 2 invitations for the same hour, on the same date. The false, makes the user to stay in the 'create'.
How can I insert a message into the create, if the before save returns false?

Here is my function:

```
 public function beforeSave($insert)
{
    $return = parent::beforeSave($insert);
      $numOfInvitations = (new yii\db\Query())
     ->from('invitation')
        ->where(['day' =>$this->day])
        ->andWhere(['hour' =>$this->hour])
        ->count();
    if ($numOfInvitations==2){

        return false;           
    }

    return $return;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

e.g.  `$this->addError('id', 'there are already 2 invitations');`

But I would add a validation function by adding this to your `rules` and check it on the validation.

```
['id', 'checkInvitations']
```

and your code in

```
function public function checkPanCardUsers($attribute, $params)
{
   if ($this->day && $this->hour) {
       $numOfInvitations = (new yii\db\Query())
        ->from('invitation')
        ->where(['day' =>$this->day])
        ->andWhere(['hour' =>$this->hour])
        ->count();
        if ($numOfInvitations==2){
           $this->addError($attribute, 'there are already 2 invitations');
        }
    }
}
```